# Why do I have performance issues when using List.IndexOf(List.Where()) inside of a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, list, performance

I am working on a solution for getting a list of bigrams and the count of each bigram, for a given input. The performance was poor with large input; execution time took about 42 seconds for input of 460,000 characters and 84,000 words. I changed the code and it’s performing fine now, but I am not sure what exactly caused the performance issue.

The commented-out code is where the issue was. I thought it would perform better if I gathered the bigram and occurrences of each bigram in 1 loop, opposed to two, but I was wrong. Getting the index of an item in a list -when passing the item parameter via **List.Where()** – does not seem to be efficient. Why? Is the predicate evaluated on each item in the list, even when using **FirstOrDefault()**?

My only thinking: even if the predicate is not evaluated on each item in the list, I could understand why using **List.IndexOf(List.Where())** is slower. If there are 84,000 items in the list, **FirstOrDefault()** has to loop through (I assume) until it finds the first match -which could be at index 0 or 83,999- and that is repeated for each item in the list.

```
public class Bigram
{
    public string Phrase { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public List<Bigram> GetSequence(string[] words)
{

  List<Bigram> bigrams = new List<Bigram>();
  List<string> bigramsTemp = new List<string>();

   for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
    {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i]) == false)
         {
            bigramsTemp.Add(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]);

             //Bigram bigram = new Bigram()
              //{
                //  Phrase = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]
               //};

                //bigrams.Add(bigram);

                //var matches = bigrams.Where(p => p.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).Count();

                //if (matches == 0)
                //{
                //    bigram.Count = 1;
                //    bigrams.Add(bigram);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                // int bigramToEdit = 
                //     bigrams.IndexOf(
                //       bigrams.Where(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).FirstOrDefault());
                //    bigrams[bigramToEdit].Count += 1;
                //}
            }
        }

        var sequences = bigramsTemp.GroupBy(i => i);

        foreach (var s in sequences)
        {
            bigrams.Add(
                new Bigram()
                {
                    Phrase = s.Key,
                    Count = s.Count()
                });
        }

        return bigrams;
    }
```

Comment: What if you use `bigrams.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase)` instead?

Comment: @mylee After 5 tests, there was 1.5 second increase in performance off of the 42 seconds

Comment: @KRob I also did the tests, mylee answer improves a lot more than 1.5 second

Comment: @ShaharShokrani mylee's answer improves by about 20 seconds; however the 1.5 seconds was referencing her comment, not answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complementary for @hans-keﬆing and @mylee answers,
Moving to Dictionary will help your code even further:

```
IDictionary<string, int> bigramsDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }

    string key = words[i] + " " words[i + 1];
    if (!bigramsDict.ContainsKey(key))
        bigramsDict.Add(key, 1);
    else
        bigramsDict[key]++;    
}
```

If you don't want to change the public signature you will need to do a conversion to List with:

```
foreach (var item in bigramsDict) {
    bigrams.add(new Bigram {Phrase = item.Key, Count = item.Value});
} 

retrun bigrams;
```

---

### Performance test

Results In milliseconds:

1. Original Code: 163835.0242.
2. mylee code: 75099.003.
3. Dictionary code: 23.76.

```c#
    public static string[] CreateRandomWords(int count)
    {
        string[] result = new string[count];

        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var stringChars = new char[8];
        var random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < stringChars.Length; j++)
            {
                stringChars[j] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            var finalString = new String(stringChars);

            result[i] = finalString;
        }

        return result;
    }


    public class Bigram
    {
        public string Phrase { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<Bigram> GetSequenceA1(string[] words)
    {
        List<Bigram> bigrams = new List<Bigram>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i]) == false)
            {
                Bigram bigram = new Bigram()
                {
                    Phrase = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]
                };

                bigrams.Add(bigram);

                var matches = bigrams.Where(p => p.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).Count();

                if (matches == 0)
                {
                    bigram.Count = 1;
                    bigrams.Add(bigram);
                }
                else
                {
                    int bigramToEdit =
                        bigrams.IndexOf(
                            bigrams.Where(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).FirstOrDefault());
                    bigrams[bigramToEdit].Count += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return bigrams;
    }

    public static List<Bigram> GetSequenceA2(string[] words)
    {
        List<Bigram> bigrams = new List<Bigram>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i]) == false)
            {
                Bigram bigram = new Bigram()
                {
                    Phrase = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]
                };

                bigrams.Add(bigram);

                var match = bigrams.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase);
                if (match == null)
                {                        
                    bigram.Count = 1;
                    bigrams.Add(bigram);
                }
                else
                {                        
                    match.Count += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return bigrams;
    }

    public static List<Bigram> GetSequenceB(string[] words)
    {
        List<Bigram> bigrams = new List<Bigram>();

        IDictionary<string, int> bigramsDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }

            string key = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1];
            if (!bigramsDict.ContainsKey(key))
                bigramsDict.Add(key, 1);
            else
                bigramsDict[key]++;
        }

        foreach (var item in bigramsDict)
        {
            bigrams.Add(new Bigram { Phrase = item.Key, Count = item.Value });
        }

        return bigrams;
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] _wordsList = CreateRandomWords(85000);

        Stopwatch stopwatchA1 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatchA1.Start();
        List<Bigram> SequenceA1 = GetSequenceA1(_wordsList);
        stopwatchA1.Stop();
        double durationA1 = stopwatchA1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("SequenceA1:" + durationA1);

        Stopwatch stopwatchA2 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatchA2.Start();
        List<Bigram> SequenceA2 = GetSequenceA2(_wordsList);
        stopwatchA2.Stop();
        double durationA2 = stopwatchA2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("SequenceA2:" + durationA2);

        Stopwatch stopwatchB = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatchB.Start();
        List<Bigram> SequenceB = GetSequenceB(_wordsList);
        stopwatchB.Stop();
        double durationB = stopwatchB.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("SequenceB:" + durationB);
    }
```

Comment: I got the same results.

Comment: Whay do you mean?

Comment: I mean that I was able to produce the same results as you, and GetSequenceB() was the quickest.

Answer (score 3):

From your initial code, which has about 4 loops through the whole bigrams array

```
var matches = bigrams.Where(p => p.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).Count();

if (matches == 0)
{
    bigram.Count = 1;
    bigrams.Add(bigram);
}
else
{
    int bigramToEdit = 
     bigrams.IndexOf(
       bigrams.Where(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase).FirstOrDefault());
    bigrams[bigramToEdit].Count += 1;
}
```

Change to the following, which has only one loop through the whole bigrams array, while keeping the logics the same

```
var match = bigrams.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Phrase == bigram.Phrase);
if (match == null)
{
    //match == null means that it does not exist in the array, which is equivalent with Count == 0
    bigram.Count = 1;
    bigrams.Add(bigram);
}
else
{
    //changing the value of match.Count is essentially the same as querying the match again using IndexOf and Where
    match.Count += 1;
}
```

Let me know how the performance goes after changing to this

Answer (score 2):

`bigrams.Where().FirstOrDefault()` loops through the list of bigrams until the first match is found.

Then `bigrams.IndexOf()` loops through that list *again* to find the index.

This is after that `bigrams.Where().Count()` had already looped through the full list.

And all this is repeated for every word.

### Some ways to speed this up:

- You can use the fact the FirstOrDefault returns a `null` when there is no match, then you can skip the Count.
- There is [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) of Where that uses the index, so you can also skip the extra IndexOf step. **But you do not need that** (as [mylee saw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761238/121309)) as you already have the bigram to update.